# Run a .tcl command from a makefile

Tags: linux, makefile, tcl

I am new to writing a makefile which will be executed on a linux machine.

I have the following tasks to do in a makefile:
1)check if the files in the path/directory are exists and modified recently
2)run a .tcl file

I have written the following piece of code..can you please help me.
PATH =/work/source/

```
task1:
    ifeq (,$(PATH))
         @echo "error file does not exist!"
    endif

    #check for files modified
    
    #run the .tcl command
    run evaltest.tcl


reports :@echo "reports tbd"


.PHONY : all 
 all: task1 reports
```

Please let me know what changes are required for it to run as expected.

Comment: Try `tclsh evaltest.tcl`.

Comment: If `PATH` is empty, the chances are _extremely_ high that the makefile will break in very many places.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be planning to do way too much work yourself. Your task #1 is typically what make does. So that only leaves task #2. If a Tcl script has the excutable permission and starts with a valid hashbang, you can just execute it. Otherwise invoke tclsh to run it.

Another problem could be that you redefined the PATH variable. On linux, the PATH variable normally contains a list of directories where executable commands can be found. To point to your sources, better use a different variable name, like SRCPATH or so. By redefining PATH, the tclsh command can not be found, unless it is in /work/source.

So the task1 rule of your Makefile could be reduced to:

```
task1: sourcefile1 sourcefile2
        tclsh evaltest.tcl
        # Or ./evaltest.tcl
```

This will execute evaltest.tcl if either sourcefile1 or sourcefile2 is newer than a file called task1. It is assumed that evaltest.tcl will create the task1 file. If either sourcefile doesn't exist and there is no rule to create it, make will tell you about that.

Comment: okay...but what if i have to check each source file from a project? can my task1 be the project name in that case? how do i compare if any of the source files have been modified/deleted? and then run the tcl after that?

Comment: Modified since when? Normally you are interested to know about changed files that were used to create something else. If some of those files are modified, the other thing needs to be regenerated. So you put the resulting file before the colon (target) and the input files after the colon (prerequisites). Of course you can make an additional empty "phony" target with a nicer name that has the output file(s) as prerequisite(s), if you want.

Comment: thanks @Schelte Bron..this was a good explaination! had a new query.can i still execute the tcl file even if nothing is changed?

Comment: If you want to run the tcl file every time you run make, include it in a phony target. If you just want to run it on occasion even when nothing has changed, invoke `make` with the -B (or --always-make) option.